# How to hide legends in highcharts in mobile view alone

Tags: css, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I need to hide legends of highcharts ng in mobile view alone so that it occupies the full width of the screen. I tried setting the class .highcharts-legend to display none using bootstrap class hidden-xs but even though it is getting hidden the chart is not occupying the full width of the screen even though the highcharts ng directive does. I have also given the id #chart1 as follows

```
 #chart1{
    height:100%  !important;
    width:100%  !important;
}
```

so that the chart always occupies the full width of the screen

Comment: there is a property calls `showInLegend` in plotOptions of highcharts, identify it's mobile or not  then set `showInLegend` to true or false

Comment: could you please provide example @QI.soa

Comment: you can disable legend using legend.enabled: false and you can use chart.marginBottom:0 for making your plotArea bigger: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginBottom

Comment: I need the legend to appear in large screens i just need to remove them in mobile and small screens

Comment: You'll need to determine whether the screen meets your criteria to show the legend, and set the `legend.enabled` property accordingly.

Comment: Could you provide example please

Answer (score 2):

This will work to hide legend if screen less than 900px:

```
  chart.legend.update({ enabled: (chart.containerWidth > 900) });
```

Likewise:

```
  legend: {
                enabled : ($('#myContainer').width() > 900)
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `responsive` property and hide the legend in some condition:

```
responsive: {
    rules: [{
        chartOptions: {
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
        }
    }]
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pds7aqr4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/responsive